# Hash Table Implementation using Java

Tags: java, hash-map

Looking for feedback on my java hash table implementation. Code uses an array of lists of entries as a sort of separate-chaining; not sure how much I prefer this approach in practice, and am considering using linear / quadratic probing instead. Table should resize above a certain load %. I also tried to handle negative hashes being generated, and use a prime # for table size in order to prevent clustering.

It seems as though there are many different methods and techniques to use when building a hash table from scratch, so any comments or suggestions on my approach, coding style, conventions, etc would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

HashTable implementation:

```
public class HashTable<K, V> {

    private ListNode<Entry<K, V>>[] table;
    private int size;
    private final int initSize = 5;
    private final double loadFactor = 0.70;
    private final int resizeFactor = 2;

    public HashTable() {
        this.table = new ListNode[this.initSize];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.table.length; i++) {
            this.table[i] = new ListNode();
        }
    }

    public V get(K key) throws Exception {
        try {
            ListNode<Entry<K, V>> bucket = getBucket(key);
            while(bucket != null) {
                if(bucket.getData().getKey().equals(key)) {
                    return bucket.getData().getValue();
                }
            }
            return null;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

    public boolean put(K key, V value) throws Exception {
        try {
            if(put(new Entry(key, value))) {
                resize();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
    private boolean put(Entry<K, V> entry) throws Exception {
        try {
            // if bucket's data at hash index is empty, add entry
            if(this.table[hashFunction(entry.getKey())] == null) { // if bucket is null
                this.table[hashFunction(entry.getKey())] = new ListNode(entry);
                this.size++;
                return true;
            } else if(this.table[hashFunction(entry.getKey())].getData() == null) { // if bucket holds no entry data
                this.table[hashFunction(entry.getKey())].setData(entry);
                this.size++;
                return true;
            } else { // if bucket contains data:
                // iterate through bucket until a. bucket with data containing key is found, b. bucket with no entry data is found, or c. null bucket is found
                ListNode<Entry<K, V>> tempBucket = this.table[hashFunction(entry.getKey())];
                if(tempBucket.getData().getKey().equals(entry.getKey())) { // if bucket contains correct entry key data
                    tempBucket.getData().setValue(entry.getValue());
                    return true;
                }
                while(tempBucket.getNext() != null) {
                    if(tempBucket.getData().getKey().equals(entry.getKey())) { // if bucket contains correct entry key data
                        tempBucket.getData().setValue(entry.getValue());
                        return true;
                    } else { // check next bucket in list
                        tempBucket = tempBucket.getNext();
                    }
                }
                // null bucket has been found, add new entry data:
                tempBucket.setNext(new ListNode(entry));
                this.size++;
                return true;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

    public boolean containsKey(K key) throws Exception {
        try {
            ListNode<Entry<K, V>> bucket = getBucket(key);
            while(bucket != null) {
                if(bucket.getData() != null) {
                    if(bucket.getData().getKey().equals(key)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                bucket = bucket.getNext();
            }
            return false;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

    public boolean remove(K key) throws Exception {
        try {
            ListNode<Entry<K, V>> bucket = getBucket(key);
            ListNode<Entry<K, V>> prev = null;
            while(bucket != null) {
                if(bucket.getData().getKey().equals(key)) {
                    break;
                }
                prev = bucket;
                bucket = bucket.getNext();
            }
            if(bucket == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if(prev != null) {
                prev.setNext(bucket.getNext());
            } else {
                this.table[hashFunction(key)] = bucket.getNext();
            }
            this.size--;
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

    private ListNode<Entry<K, V>> getBucket(K key) {
        return this.table[hashFunction(key)];
    }

    private int hashFunction(K key) {
        int hash = key.hashCode() % this.table.length;
        return (hash < 0) ? hash * -1 : hash;
    }

    private void resize() throws Exception {
        try {
            if(this.size / (double)this.table.length > this.loadFactor) {
                int newSize = this.table.length * this.resizeFactor;
                while(newSize % 2 == 0 || newSize % 3 == 0) { // find > double current size prime number for new table size.
                    newSize++;
                }
                SinglyLinkedList<ListNode<Entry<K, V>>> oldEntries = new SinglyLinkedList(); // store current data to be rehashed later.
                for(int i = 0; i < this.table.length; i++) {
                    if(this.table[i].getData() != null) {
                        oldEntries.insertEnd(this.table[i]);
                    }
                }
                this.table = new ListNode[newSize];
                for(int i = 0; i < this.table.length; i++) {
                    this.table[i] = new ListNode();
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < oldEntries.getSize(); i++) { // rehash old values into newly-allocated array.
                    ListNode<Entry<K, V>> oldEntry = oldEntries.getElementAt(i);
                    while(oldEntry != null) {
                        put(oldEntry.getData().getKey(), oldEntry.getData().getValue());
                        this.size--; // ensure that size isn't being artificially inflated during rehash
                        oldEntry = oldEntry.getNext();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

    public int getSize() throws Exception {
        try {
            return this.size;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() throws Exception {
        try {
            return this.size <= 0;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Entry class, used within HashTable:

```
public class Entry<K, V> {
    private K key;
    private V value;

    public Entry() {}

    public Entry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(K key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this at all?  Your `HashTable.get` method doesn't seem to advance `bucket`, so it would infinite loop whenever the first value isn't the right value.

Comment: @mdfst13 I have written some tests, but I guess I must have missed that case. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Please add null check for 'keys' I am assuming you are getting a NPE, if key==null.
2. If key == null, then hashcode is 0.
3. In the while loop in 'get' method, I am struggling to understand, where you are advancing to next entry in the same bucket ?
4. Your Entry class can contain 'next' pointer, such that it behaves like a linkedlist.
5. `ListNode<Entry<K, V>> bucket = getBucket(key);` this can be made `final` since its not changed in scope of method. Similarly `final K key` can be added.
6. In your `get` method you are catching and throwing the same exception. You would typically catch an exception only if you want to pad it with additional message or cast it into a more generic exception.
7. You always call `resize` and there is a logic inside `resize` that tells you wether to proceed with `resize` or not. Now, if you could either rename it to `tryResize` or do the check before calling `resize` it would be more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

**Advice 1**

The problem behind open addressing (probing) is that the operations slow down far beyond \$\Theta(1)\$ which is pretty much guaranteed by collision chains (your current implementation) under assumption that the load factor and the hash function are reasonable. Advice: stick to collision chains.

**Advice 2**

You explicitly create an entire table of `ListNode` objects. I suggest you roll something like

```
// Partially a pseudocode.
private static final class CollisionChainNode<K, V> {
    private final K key;
    private V value;
    private CollisionChainNode<K, V> prev;
    private CollisionChainNode<K, V> next;
    private final int keyHashCode; // This may add to performance if the key is a string/collection. For the node, the key is `final`, so that you need to compute that only once.
}
```

... and you populate the actual hash `table` only there where needed.

**Advice 3**

You are prepared to catch some exceptions. That is not quite correct when dealing with data structures in general: you should make sure via invariants that the data structure works as expected. The only exception you may need to throw/catch are those that are related to resources; most usually, memory.

Comment: Thanks for the response! When you mention using 'invariants' in order to verify that the data structure works as expected, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @koprulu Basically, you need to master your code such that it cannot throw, say, `NullPointerException` or any other exception that is not caused by exhaustion of resources (such as memory). We can always run out of memory; nothing we can do here,  but your algorithms must be written such that  they cannot "break" otherwise.

Comment: I disliked this because probing can work faster, even when you consider collisions if you use a good collision resolution system. Python for example uses a version where you shift in 5 bits of hash code at a time, with some mixing factors to ensure that large numbers of collisions are rare. Here is a link explaining the approach. https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Objects/dictobject.c#l33

Comment: @Oscar Smith Fair enough. Any suggestions how I could improve my answer?

Comment: If you removed the "probing is bad", I'd remove the down-vote. If you added a brief bit explaining with more nuance what the relative advantages/disadvantages were, it would be a stronger answer.